# program that inputs a string that represents a binary number

Tags: java, string, binary-data

Write a program that inputs a string that represents a binary number. The string can contain only 0s and 1s
and no other characters, not even
spaces. Validate that the entered number meets these requirements. If it
does not, display an error message. If it
is a valid binary number, determine the number of 1s that it
contains. If it has exactly two 1s, display "Accepted". Otherwise, display "Rejected".
All input and output
should be from the console.
Here are some sample inputs to test:
abc
10102011
10101FF
0000 1111 (note the space in this test case)
00000000
1111
01110000001
1000001

```
import javax.swing.JOptionPane;
import java.text.DecimalFormat;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class binarynumber
{
  public static void main(String [] args )
  {
Scanner scan = new Scanner (System.in);
String number;
System.out.print("Enter an binary number.");
number = scan.nextLine();
int n = 0;
for( int i = number.length(););
  {

char binarynumber = number.charAt(n);
if(binarynumber != 1)
    {
     System.out.print("Error, That was not a valid entry.");
    }
else if(binarynumber= 0)
    {
     System.out.print("Error, That was not a valid entry.");
    }
else
  }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

- You're looping but never incrementing `i`
- You're using `n` to check `charAt()` when you should use `i`
- Your `if(binarynumber= 0)` should be `if(binarynumber == 0)`
- Your last `else` has no opening bracket

Comment: One more: if the number is 0, it will enter the `if(binarynumber != 1)` and output `error`